# Speedup ExecuteReader in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using a C# `SqlDataReader` in many loops. Unfortunately I can't read the whole table and store the data in a list. So I have to create a `SqlDataReader` again and again. Once the `SqlDataReader` is created, its very fast. But the creation of the `SqlDataReader` via `ExecuteReader` takes too much time.

Is there any possibility to improve the creation time of the `SqlDataReader`?

I'm using .NET 4.5.1 and SQL Server 2008.

```
string sql = "select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP";
var connection = Connections.Get();

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
```

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Can you post your code how to read data?

Comment: Without seeing your code we will not be able to guess what's might be going wrong.

Comment: How much time does the data reader to get created...?

Comment: Recreating the DataReader is going to be where you take the most performance impact, why do you need to recreate it in a loop instead of creating it once and then parsing the data?

Comment: why can't you read the table at once using `DataAdaptar`?

Comment: @Michael - and also try wrapping calls to `SqlCommand` inside a `using` block to ensure proper memory management.

Comment: The reason for the performance difference between creation and usage of an SqlDataReader is possibly due to the fact that the real work, i.e. getting the data from the db is done in the creation phase, and the read only accesses a memory buffer. This is backed by the fact that a reader reads stale data when an update takes place between the creation and usage of a SqlDataReader.

Answer (score 0):

```
string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select  TOP 50000 * from users", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
```

please use `DataTable` and `SqlDataAdapter` to read the data 
Instead of using `ExecuteReader`

Comment: This is kind of  suggestion and doesn't answer the question.Provide comments/questions in the comment section next to the question.

Comment: We can not use ExecuteReader to read large rows. This will cause function evaluation time out so, better use DataTable and SqlDataAdapter